# RegEx match with an exception in it

Tags: javascript, regex

I search for a way to match with exceptions in it.
For example I want to match `ab-3/3/6`, but I dont want to match `ab-4/2/5:34`.
Also if `ab-4/2/5:34` exists... I dont want to match it at all.

For this solution I build the following regex: `ab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}[^:]`

My problem here is that my desired match only works if there are still characters behind them (like a whitespace, or a new line). So for example I have the following text:

```
ab-3/3/6
ab-4/2/5:34
ab-6/1/4
```

My match only contains `ab-3/3/6`.
That it dind't find `ab-4/2/5` is what I want to archive.
But `ab-6/1/4` is missing, because here is no character behind it.

Can someone please help me to finde a solution for this problem?

Comment: Change it to a negative lookahead `\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?!:)` https://regex101.com/r/eIqWdC/1

Comment: Are you validating entire strings? Use anchors, `^ab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}$`. If you extract, you need `\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?![:\d])`

Comment: I'm trying to match in a big text. `\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?!:)` and `\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?![:\d])` both are working. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Both cannot work for you. So, you want to extract `ab-3/3/69` from a `ab-3/3/6987`, right?

Comment: Both can work if `ab-3/3/6987` is not present

Comment: Oh I understand... hm... I never thought about `ab-3/3/6987`.  Then my prefered solution is `\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?![:\d])`... although I don't think that these cases could happen to me.

Comment: If that pattern is your solution @Wiktor Stribiżew could also post his pattern and you can accept his solution.

Comment: I will do. Thanks to both of you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), you need to use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). However, since the last pattern before the lookbehind is quantified and the pattern match length is not known, the regex engine might *backtrack* and match a string that you would want to fail. It means *you can't just replace `[^:]` with `(?!:)`*.

An example string that *should not* get matched can be `ab-3/3/6987`: the [`/\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?!:)/`](https://regex101.com/r/FdYmur/1) will grab `69` with the last `\d{1,2}` and then the `(?!:)` lookahead will check that `8` is not `:`, and will return "OK". You will get a  `ab-3/3/69` match.

You need to either use a word boundary before the lookahead (if the next char cannot be a letter, digit, or `_`), or you may just add `\d` to `:`, i.e. use `(?![:\d])` (then, you will get matches before a letter or `_`).

So, use either

```
\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?![:\d])
//                            ^^^^^^^^^   
\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\b(?!:)
//                            ^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/FdYmur/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/FdYmur/3). See how differently  they behave with additional inputs.

Comment: Here comes 400K congrats :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Wow, thank you :) I did not even notice. Sounds like a birthday present.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :D It really helps.

Answer (score 1):

A negated character class matches any character except the listed which is a `:`, but it does expect a character to be there (for example a whitespace or a newline or another digit)

You could start the match with a word boundary `\b` to prevent *ab* being part of a longer word and end the pattern with a negative lookahead `(?!:)` asserting not a `:` after 1 or 2 digits.

```
\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?!:)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e1Ba3Y/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I'm getting it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be : `/ab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?<!:)$/`

**Sample:**

```js
const dateStr = `ab-3/3/6
ab-4/2/5:34
ab-6/1/4`;

const matchAll = (str) => {
  let m;
  const reg = /ab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?<!:)$/gm;
  let result = [];
  do {
    m = reg.exec(str);
    if (m) {
      result.push(m[0]);
    }
  } while (m);
  return result;
};
console.log(matchAll(dateStr));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This pattern seems to work too I guess... don't really know what the difference between yours and `\bab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?![:\d])` is.

Comment: one is lookbehind, one is look ahead.. yo can learn here:

https://regex101.com/

Comment: `/ab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}(?<!:)$/` = `/ab-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}$/` and it is basically my first suggestion without `^` - it was reported as not working.